# In elasticsearch how to filter in csv string field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, I have products index where the categories are stored as a csv string in one field. I am using the php client, and my current search code looks like

```
$params = [
            "index" => "products",
            "type" => "product",
            "body" => [
                "size" => "5",
                "query" => [
                    "function_score" => [
                        "query" => [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    "query_string" => [
                                        "fields" => ["category", "sub_category", "website", "services_offered", "keyword", "locations", "info"],
                                          "query" => $keyword."*"
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "filter" => [
                                    "term"=> ["is_active"=>1]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "functions" => [
                                        [
                                            "field_value_factor" => ["field" => "rating", "modifier" => "none", "factor" => 1]
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            "field_value_factor" => ["field" => "reviews","modifier" => "log1p","factor" => 2]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $results = $this->elasticclient->search($params);
```

I tried modifying the `filter` array like

```
"filter" => [
                                    "term"=> ["is_active"=>1],
                                        "wildcard" => ["category"=>$category]
                                ]
```

But I get a `malformed query,  expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]` error.

Also on a sidenote, in the php client, how can I get the final generated query for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The `terms` filter doesn't support wildcards. You can use `regexp` filter instead (Queries in Elasticsearch version >= 2.0).